# How do I loop through an array of objects that's within an array of objects and display in my HTML using Angular/Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-directive, angular2-directives

I have an interface like so:

```
export interface SeriesCard {
  type: string,
  imageUrl: string,
  title: string,
  category: string,
  seriesItems: SeriesItems[];
}
```

My Service already has mocked data and my `.ts` file looks like:

```
seriesCard: SeriesCard[];
  title: string = "";

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController,
              private cardService: CardsService,
              private navExtraService: NavExtrasServiceService) { }

  navigateToPage(seriesItems: SeriesItems) {
    this.navExtraService.setExtras(seriesItems);
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward([`video-component`]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.seriesCard = this.cardService.getSeriesCardsArray();
    console.log(this.seriesCard);
  }
```

in my HTML file, I'm doing an *ngFor to loop through my seriesCard like so:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid class="ion-no-padding">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let cards of seriesCard; let i = index">
        <ion-list class="ion-list-background">
          <ion-item (click)="navigateToPage(cards.seriesItems[i])" class="ion-item-background" lines="none" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #343436;">
            <ion-avatar slot="start">
              <img src="{{cards.seriesItems[i].imageUrl}}" alt="">
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-label>
              <h2 style="color: #ffffff">{{cards.seriesItems[i].title}}</h2>
              <ion-text class="smaller">{{cards.seriesItems[i].description}}</ion-text>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

My issue is that I need to loop through my `SeriesItems[]` that's within my `SeriesCard[]` in my HTML. How do I do that? Because currently, in my mock data, I have 2 `SeriesCards` objects, each with 4 `SeriesItems` objects. But my *ngFor is only looping twice because it's looping at the top level instead of a level down (`SeriesItems[]`).

How do I fix this?

I tried adding another *ngFor but it wasn't working quite right.. I appreciate any support.

**EDIT:** I have already tried a second *ngFor. The HTML that I showed above is supposed to display the # of `SeriesItems` within a single `SeriesCard`. In this case, It would show 4 items, not 8!

Answer (score 0):

You need another `*ngFor` on `<ion-item>` tag because SeriesItems[] is array.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let seriesItem of cards.seriesItems">
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
       <img src="{{seriesItem.imageUrl}}" alt="">
    </ion-avatar>
    <ion-label>
       <h2 style="color: #ffffff">{{seriesItem.title}}</h2>
       <ion-text class="smaller">{{seriesItem.description}}</ion-text>
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't quite work because adding that for loop, within the other for loop make it so there's double of everything, because I'm already looping..

Comment: For instance, when I add that for loop, and then in my <ion-label> tag, I do {{seriesItems.title}}, it will display 8 times, when in fact, there are only 4 SeriesItems objects within each SeriesCard object.

Comment: @Donnygroezinger you have 2 SeriesCards objects, each with 4 SeriesItems objects so 8 times is right!

Comment: and use `{{seriesItem.title}}` not `{{seriesItems.title}}`

Comment: But that's not what I want!

Comment: Please look at my Edit